# Is `div > a` the same thing as `div a`?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

In CSS, are the selectors `div > a` and `div a` the same?

```
<div>
  <a>Hi</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: @close voters: Down-vote if you like, but voting to close makes no sense. It's definitely a real question (though poorly worded) and it's definitely on-topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It isn't. "`div > a`" is a [*child selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-CSS2-20101207/selector.html#child-selectors); it means "an `a` element that's an *immediate child* of a `div`". "`div a`" is a [*descendant selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-CSS2-20101207/selector.html#descendant-selectors); it means "an `a` element that's a *descendant* of a `div`" (a child, or the child of a child, or the child of a child of a child, ...). All child elements are, of course, descendants; but not all descendants are children.

So for instance:

```
<div>
  <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>
</div>
```

matches both `div > a` and `div a` (the `a` is a child element of a `div`, and of course all child elements are also descendant elements).

But:

```
<div>
  <span>
    <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

...doesn't match `div > a` but does match `div a`, because the `a` is a descendant but *not* an immediate child (there's a `span` in-between).

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/okote)

Comment: oh, so then "div > a" it wouldn't work if the "<a>" was inside another "<span>"?

Comment: @funk-shun: Exactly. In fact, I just added an example to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

It's not.

```
<div><h1><a>some text</a></h1></div>
```

In the HTML above, `div > a` will not select the `<a>` because it's not a direct child of `<div>`.

Answer (score 2):

## [They're not the same.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

Comment: ...because reading manuals tends to be about as appealing as watching paint dry. w3c isn't too bad, but I use the [ECMA Script](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) to help me fall asleep.

Comment: @funk-shun, ever heard of JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same. The first selects only `a` elements that are *children* of `div` elements, while the second selects all `a` elements that are *descendants* of `div` elements, e.g. `<div><p><a>...</a></p></div>`.